# scheduling and resource allocation in apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, resource-scheduling

I am trying to understand how the resource allocation happens in spark. I
understand the resourceOffer method in taskScheduler. This method takes
care of locality factor while allocating the resources. This resourceOffer
method gets invoked by the corresponding cluster manager.

I am working on stand-alone spark cluster. But I am not able to locate
starting point of the resource allocation. I want to understand from end to
end how exactly resource allocations happens, given a new Application to
the Spark. Also, apart from mesos, there is a folder called Local in the
Scheduler. Can someone tell me which all files should I look into to
understand the resource allocation in stand-alone spark cluster and what is
this "Local" for?

Thanks in advance!!
Karthik.